# Fullscreen scrollview blocking clicks to layers below how to "click through"?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a scrolling background with different layers, i do this with different Layouts in scrollviews that scroll with different speeds to create a 3D effect.

I know this feels like a really bad solution but i don't know how to do it in a different way (if someone know a solution to this parallax effect you are very welcome to teach :D!)

Anyway i really want a scrollview that is in the front layer so if the user scrolls anywhere on the screen this scrollview set the ScrollX on all the other Scrolls.
the problem is that i got buttons and stuff behind on the other layers that i can't reach because the front scroll is blocking all clicks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

Comment: no more like a landscape with top,mid and bottom layer where top layer move fastest mid layer normal and bottom layer slow. i already achieve this with 3 horizontal scrolls and i set the ScrollX so i kinda simulate different speeds.
But the 4 scroll view that is in front (transparent) is the scroll that the user actually scrolls at blocking all clips on the screen.